# An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: tensorflow, kernel, compatibility

I have installed all necessary software (*opencv, tensorflow-gpu, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pandas, keras 2*) to run my code and validated them each. I am using Spyder as an IDE and going to train CNN in Keras with Tensorflow backend. I could run my code snippets until I reach training stage:

```
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=num_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

When I run this line training somewhat starts and instead of displaying the epochs and other attributes (*val_acc, training_acc, etc*) the kernel suddenly dies, then re-connects to kernel and dies again, etc.
At the end I get this error:

```
2018 16:25:49.961500: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018 16:25:50.664501: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 740 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0715
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.00GiB freeMemory: 756.79MiB
2018 16:25:50.664501: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018 16:25:51.148102: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 501 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0)
2018 16:27:22.549779: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018 16:27:22.549779: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 224 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0)
2018 16:27:43.118021: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:378] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7101 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7003 (compatibility version 7000). If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match. If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
2018 16:27:43.164821: F C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream‑>parent()‑>GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)
```

I though it is a Spyder problem and issued on [github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6694) and received a reply that is not Spyder-related but  compatibility problem

I searched the web hoping I could find solution to this, but it seems there is no exact same issue. (at least among I came across)

If there is someone who had the same problem, help me please.
What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when l was using the Jupyter notebook, the fix for me was changing the browser l was running the code with.
If using a different IDE (e.g. Jupyter notebook, pycharm) does not work l would recommend running the script from terminal/command prompt.